# generic input <T extends GenParent> with apache cxf in java - spring

Tags: java, web-services, spring, rest, generics

Can we have generics as web-method arguments?
for eg
    **In interface**

```
@WebResult(name = "genericTest")
    @WebMethod
    public <T extends GenParent> String testGeneric(T t);
```

and **in impl** :

```
 @Override
    @POST
    @Path("/generic")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    public <T extends GenParent> String testGeneric(T t) {
    return t.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
```

these sample class are:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class GenParent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6189314185893149450L;

    private String a;
    private String b;
    // getter and setter    
}


public class GenChild extends GenParent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7802747637373336039L;

    private String c;

    //getter and setter   
}
```

So when I call this web-method , I would pass Xml equivalent of GenChild.

Is it possible?

Comment: You seem to have all the classes.  Why don't you try it and let us know.

Comment: What would be the advantage over it simply taking a `GenParent` anyway?